# Angular HostListener with custom event : possible?

Tags: angular, custom-events

I wonder if I can catch up with custom event (EventEmiter). I have a child component that emit event with @Output('myCustomEvent).

Can I catch it in my parent component with @HostListener('myCustomEvent') ?

I try to di this so I get rid of the (myCustomEvent)="myMethod" in my html, which I think my be better (cleaner html code).

Can I do that ?

Thank you ahead for your help :)

Comment: yes, you can dispatch a bubbling even with a simple javascript and catch it with listener, but this way you will make unexpectable bahavior for other developers and you'll loose the typesafety that @Outputs and template event bindings provide

Answer (score -1):

You can listen to custom events with `HostListener`, however you need to listen to the element which dispatches the event.

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use the window to dispatch the event:

```
// some component class:
produceEvent() {
  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("yourEventType", {detail: yourData}))
}
```

Then in the component which needs to listen for these events you would simply wire up the HostListener to listen for your event:

```
// some other component class:
@Component({template: ''})
export class SomeOtherComponent {
  @HostListener("window:yourEventType", ["$event"])
  eventHandlerFunction(event: any) { 
     // process event here:
  }
}
```

I don't know if I would recommend this approach, as you are circumventing the normal Angular structure of utilizing Services. See: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: Hi @Mikkle Christensen ! Thank you for your answer. Indeed I think it is not a good idea and I should user service or even a state maybe .

Answer (score -1):

I would say no.

"Host" here is where the directive attached to. Yes, it's meant to use with directive not component.
And here is the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) from Angular:

> The child's EventEmitter property is an **output property**

I mean, they have a name for it - output property => @output event. They go hand in hand together.

Comment: Hello @Jimmy ! Thank you for the answer. Yeah I kind of supposed this wasn't possible regarding angular methodology. Indeed it might be better to handle that through a service. Thank you again.

Comment: actually, I was talking your mentioned statement "`cleaner html code`", in this particular situation, you shouldn't opt for this purpose, even you can.